# Is it possible you instatiate a variable in SQL server using a select statement with another variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am attempting to DECLARE a variable then SET it's value using a secondary variable which has already had it's value set.

I have tried:

```
DECLARE @Type VARCHAR = 'Some unique text';
DECLARE @TypeId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER; 

SET @TypeId = 
(
    SELECT Id
    FROM Types
    WHERE Name = @Type
)

select @TypeId
```

To no avail. The result of the final SELECT statement is null. The following works:

```
DECLARE @TypeId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER; 

SET @TypeId = 
(
    SELECT Id
    FROM Types
    WHERE Name = 'Some unique text'
)

select @TypeId
```

but I have several tables linked via dependencies and to delete an entry I need to traverse the tables in the correct order pulling the correct Ids. It is likely I will need to do this frequently so I want to reduce the leg work and just enter the text once and the script do the rest.

Is the syntax wrong or is this not possible?

Comment: Those are the perils of [declaring `VARCHAR` without a length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length), which you should never do. `@Type` is `S`.

Comment: A simple `select @Type` after you try and assign it will show you the issue .

Comment: I guess `SELECT Id FROM Types WHERE Name = @Type` doesn't return any rows. Not that if there is more than one record returned, it's arbitrary what will go into your variable. Your code can be simplified to `SELECT @TypeId = Id FROM Types WHERE Name = @Type`

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: it isn't arbitrary -- `SET @x = (SELECT ..)` is an error if the subquery returns more than one row, so this is actually a good pattern if you want to trip that. It's `SELECT @x = ...` which is arbitrary.

Comment: @JeroenMostert appreciate the reply. I have declared a length, NVARCHAR(80), and it works perfectly for grabbing the Id but the second I attempt to use that Id within the next statement I get back null again. Does the UNIQUEIDENTIFIER data type have similar quirks in this context?

Comment: No, it doesn't. If you get back no matches it suggests your value isn't what you expect it to be. Use `SELECT` or `PRINT` to verify. (Also note that variables do not persist across batches, so if you have `GO` in there or you're executing statements individually, you need to declare the variables separately every time, and they'll start off empty every time.) Do note that it's likely you don't need this variable-on-variable action; it looks like you're writing a lot of `JOIN`s as single steps.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data and query which we can run to see this (DBFiddle fine).

Comment: @JeroenMostert I appreciate the insight. Working a charm. I will look into practicing joins and see what comes of it. For now this works a treat!

Comment: @JeroenMostert lol @ variable-on-variable action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `DECLARE @Type VARCHAR = 'Some unique text';`

It seems like you try to configure the variable value to be 'Some unique text' but since the type of the variable is VARCHAR(1) then when you set the value the server implicitly CONVERT it to VARCHAR(1) which lead to trunctaing the string and using only the first character

```
DECLARE @Type VARCHAR = 'Some unique text';
SELECT @Type
GO -- result is "S" and not "Some unique text"
```

To clarify, using `DECLARE @Type VARCHAR` without explicitly set the length is translated into 'DECLARE @Type VARCHAR(1)'

As a result of this issue, your comparing of the value probably result with no rows since you compare "S" and not "Some unique text". Your sub query is the same as `SELECT Id FROM Types WHERE Name = 'S'`

Here is a simple illustration of the issue

```
------------ DDL+DML: Creating sample table with some data
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1, t2
GO

CREATE TABLE t1 (
    ID int, [Name] NVARCHAR(100)
)
GO

INSERT t1 (ID, [Name]) Values 
(1, 'Mobile '),
(2, 'TV     '),
(3, 'Display')
GO

----------- Using VARCHAR without length returns nothing

DECLARE @Type VARCHAR = 'Mobile';
SELECT @Type

DECLARE @TypeId INT; 
SET @TypeId = 
(
    SELECT Id FROM t1 WHERE Name = @Type
)
select @TypeId


----------- Using VARCHAR(100) works great
DECLARE @Type VARCHAR(100) = 'Mobile';
SELECT @Type

DECLARE @TypeId INT; 
SET @TypeId = 
(
    SELECT Id FROM t1 WHERE Name = @Type
)
select @TypeId
```